# Do I use fopen or curl to load an XML file given a URL in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, fopen

I have an XML file I can get via a URL.  I know I can get the file using `fopen`, but sometimes I've seen scripts use `curl`.  Is there an advantage to using `curl` over `fopen` to get XML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are going to use SimpleXML to load the file you can use

```
simplexml_load_file($filename);
```

However, some servers will restrict loading urls from this function.  In this case you would be restricted to cURL.

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution for me to try first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[**`allow_url_fopen`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), which is required if you want to open a remote file with `fopen`, can be disabled ; so, there are situations in which `fopen('http://...')` is not possible.

Note : in this answer, I say "`fopen`", but it's exactly the same with all PHP functions that can access remote files : `fopen`, `file_get_contents`, `simplexml_load_file`, ...

On the other hand, [**curl**](https://www.php.net/curl) is an extension, and is not always enabled either.

One nice with curl is that it's pretty easy to configure, and there are a lot of existing options *(see [`curl_setopt`][3])*

To configure the way `fopen` accesses remote files, it's a bit trickier -- you'll generally have to work with streams *(see [here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), for example)* ; and, generally speaking, there are more people knowing curl than there are developpers mastering streams.

Safest way -- especially if your application will be deployed to servers on which you are not administrator, and cannot re-configure :

- Try one solution
- And, if it doesn't work, try the other one

Answer (score 1):

fopen is simpler to use, and I think not all server setups support curl out of the box. If fopen works fine for you it's probably your best choice.