# Is it possible to cast a SimpleXML object to a DOMDocument object in PHP?

Tags: php, simplexml, domdocument

As a follow up to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739754/do-i-use-fopen-or-curl-to-load-an-xml-file-given-a-url-in-php/2739782#2739782), I'm thinking of using `simplexml_load_file` to load an XML file from a URL.

Would it be possible for me to turn that `SimpleXML` object to a `DOMDocument` object via `(DOMDocument)$my_simplexml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [**`dom_import_simplexml`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) function.

Quoting :

```
DOMElement dom_import_simplexml  (  SimpleXMLElement $node  )
```

> This function takes the node node of
>   class [`SimpleXML`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php)  and makes it
>   into a [`DOMElement`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) node. This
>   new object can then be used as a
>   native [`DOMElement`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) node.

And, just so it's said, the exact opposite manipulation can be done using [**`simplexml_import_dom`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php).

*Well, it's not a "cast" ; it's a function-call... But I guess that would still be OK for your ;-)*

Comment: Well, this answers the whole type casting part.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

As previously mentionned, [dom_import_simplexml()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) will return a DOMElement, from which you can get the related DOMDocument:

```
$doc = dom_import_simplexml($my_simplexml)->ownerDocument;
```

If you don't plan to actually use SimpleXML though, you can load the document directly from DOM.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($url);
```